# Nexus 7 New version resolution issue with resource folder

Tags: android, android-resources, nexus-7, android-resolution

My android app is working fine with old nexus 7. But I have one issue with new nexus 7 devices. 
 All the dynamic rendering (Image size and Text size) spoil the design like

```
tv1.setTextSize(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.legend_text));
```

here I mentioned 4 folder named as :-

```
values-large-hdpi
values-large-xhdpi
values-xlarge-hdpi
values-xlarge-mdpi
```

and in all above folder dimen.legend_text have value 11sp. but when i trace out the value of `getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.legend_text)` it gives me `18.`

here is my log :-
`11-18 12:09:29.758: D/size of text foe nexus 7(4794): size of text foe nexus 7 is 18.0`

any one have any idea which resource folder is fit for new nexus 7 (1920*1200 resolution).

Comment: Why are you so sure, 18px is not the right value for 11sp on your n7? Btw: qualifiers large and xlarge are deprecated since android 3.1 or something.

Comment: I debug it and print the value of `getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.legend_text)` in my log and it shows me as 11-18 12:09:29.758: D/size of text foe nexus 7(4794): size of text foe nexus 7 is 18.0

Comment: I got that. But why is 18 wrong? You know that sp!=px, right?

Comment: yes right but for old nexus 7 its working fine. and i am not able to find out the exact folder for its resource. from where its taking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you're using `9sp` means `(px = sp*(dpi/160))` so with this formula `px = 9*(320/160)` means 18.
This is the reason you're getting the value 18. 
In place of `9sp` or `11sp` keep it `9px` and your problem will solve for now. 
Regarding folder issue: Use `large-xhdpi` or `sw600dp-xhdpi`.

Answer (score 1):

tvdpi is the correct folder for nexus 7

Comment: There is also a folder with name "nodpi". It is like a neutral folder. Try in this

Comment: Is there any difference between default folder with no specification and folder with "nodpi" ?